# vuejs2 and chosen select issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Good day, pls have a look at [this bin](http://jsfiddle.net/sz8s99xx/12/). It was written Vue 0.12 version and [chosen js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). How can i make it work with vue2 version. i really need this as a directive not as a component.

```
`<div id='search`-results'>
Vue model value <br>
{{city | json}}
<hr>
Select value:
<!-- note the `v-model` and argument for `v-chosen`  --> 
<select class="cs-select" v-model="city" options="cities" v-chosen="city"></select>

<select v-model="city" options="cities"></select>
```

```
Vue.directive('chosen', {
    twoWay: true, // note the two-way binding
    bind: function () {
        $(this.el)
            .chosen({
                inherit_select_classes: true,
                width: '30%',
                disable_search_threshold: 999
            })
            .change(function(ev) {
                this.set(this.el.value);
            }.bind(this));
    },
    update: function(nv, ov) {
        // note that we have to notify chosen about update
        $(this.el).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
      city: 'Toronto',
      cities: [{text: 'Toronto', value: 'Toronto'}, 
               {text: 'Orleans', value: 'Orleans'}]
  }
}).$mount("#search-results");
```

Comment: I think "I need this as a directive in Vue2" equates to "I need someone to help me do this the wrong way." There is no two-way binding in directives in Vue2.

Comment: the reason i want to keep this in a directive, is i have a lot attributes on select element and i dont want to pass to component.

Comment: You may have asked the wrong question, then. Possibly "how can I reasonably pass all these attributes to a wrapper component" is what you're looking for.

Comment: This may be useful: https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/

Comment: Thanks for the post on this. The official Vue.js docs also has a similar example component wrapper for a jQuery plugin: select2 https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is implemented as a wrapper component that supports `v-model` and a slot for the options. This makes it a drop-in replacement for a standard `select` widget, at least as far as basic functionality. The `updated()`, happily, will notice changes to the options list as well as to the value.

Since two-way directives are not supported in Vue2, I do not believe there is a way to implement this as a directive. If you really need that, you will want to use Vue1.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#search-results',
  data: {
    city: 'Toronto',
    cities: [{
      text: 'Toronto',
      value: 'Toronto'
    }, {
      text: 'Orleans',
      value: 'Orleans'
    }]
  },
  components: {
    'chosenSelect': {
      template: '<select class="cs-select" v-model="proxyValue" ><slot></slot></select>',
      props: ['value', 'options'],
      computed: {
        proxyValue: {
          get() {
            return this.value;
          },
          set(newValue) {
            this.$emit('input', newValue);
          }
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        $(this.$el)
          .chosen({
            inherit_select_classes: true,
            width: '30%',
            disable_search_threshold: 999
          })
          .change((ev) => {
            this.proxyValue = ev.target.value;
          });
      },
      updated() {
        $(this.$el).trigger('chosen:updated');
      }
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => { vm.cities.push({text: 'Houston', value: 'Worth it'}); }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.proto.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='search-results'>
  Vue model value
  <br> {{city | json}}
  <hr> Select value:
  <chosen-select v-model="city">
    <option v-for="item in cities" :value="item.value">{{item.text}}</option>
  </chosen-select>

  <select v-model="city">
    <option v-for="item in cities" :value="item.value">{{item.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```