# What is the difference between updated hook and watchers in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I'm discovering VueJS and I don't understand exactly the differences between `updated` and watchers.

### Updated hook

It is a lifecycle hook. According to [the official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), it is triggered whenever data changes. So whenever a `prop` or a `data` is updated (the value, not only the pointer), `updated` is called.

### Watchers

In the documentation, watchers are compared to computed properties. But in which cases would it be best to use updated instead of watchers ?

It seems that in both cases, DOM is not updated when the callback is called (`nextTick()` is required if we want to manipulate the changes in the DOM). The only difference I see is that `watchers` are only triggered when one precise property (or data) is updated where `updated` is always called.

I can't figure out what are the pros of updating whenever a data changes (`updating`) if we can be more accurate (`watchers`).

Here are my thoughts.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The lifecycle hooks around update respond to **changes in the DOM**. Watchers respond to **changes in the data**. DOM changes are generally in response to data changes, but they might not be data owned by the component in question. One example where `updated` could be used is [noticing that slot content has updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291126/392102).

Comment: the current vue documentation doesn't support this view. While they mention you could use the updated hook to perform DOM operations, they suggest it's better to avoid this and use a watcher instead.  
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#updated

Comment: @TheFool The whole point is that watchers respond to data changes, while the updated hooks are called after DOM changes. That is the difference. That is still what the docs say.

Comment: Ok, I see, makes sense. They don't fire on value change, but on DOM change.

Answer (score 10):

I think a better analogous lifecycle hook to the watchers may be [the beforeUpdate hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeUpdate). The `updated` hook is called *after* the virtual DOM has re-rendered, whereas `beforeUpdate` is called *before* the virtual DOM has re-rendered. You can see a visual representation of this [on the diagram you linked to](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

---

> in which cases would it be best to use updated instead of watchers ? (...) I can't figure out what are the pros of updating whenever a data changes (`updated`) if we can be more accurate (`watch`).

[The documentation says](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) that you should prefer a watcher or computed property instead of `updated` if it is possible to achieve your goal that way. My understanding is that the `updated` hook was included to allow users to watch for any changes to the virtual DOM (see below).

---

Here's the explanation from [the Vue 2.0 release notes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873) on `watch` vs. `updated`:

> User watchers created via `vm.$watch` are now fired before the associated component re-renders. This gives the user a chance to further update other state before the component re-render, thus avoiding unnecessary updates. For example, you can watch a component prop and update the component's own data when the prop changes.
>
> To do something with the DOM after component updates, just use the `updated` lifecycle hook.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  What situations does it make sense to use the `beforeUpdate` hook instead of the `watch` hook?    Assuming there is only one data attribute for a component, and we decide to watch that data attribute, is there any difference between the two?

Comment: My impression is that `watch` is the better option when you only want code to run when a particular variable changes.