# When is a component re-rendered?

Tags: vue.js

Am trying to improve the performance of my vuejs app, and I cant figure out why some components are re-rendering...

According to the [hook's lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), a component should re-render

> when data changes

Looking here and there I assume this means a change to either `$props` or `$data`, but I must be wrong because often neither of them are modified but still the `beforeUpdate` and `updated` hooks are triggered meaning it is indeed re-rendered. So when is a component re-rendered?

EDIT: how do I see that neither `$props` nor `$data` are modified? I set a deep watcher on each of them, and these watchers are not triggered

EDIT 2: in addition to `$props` and `$data`, a change to any slots would also cause a re-render. This explain some cases but still, I have some components without any slots for which the `updated` hook is triggered without `$props` or `$data` being changed

EDIT 3: apparently if a component has a prop that is an object and some other part of this object is modified, it may trigger an update of the component... still trying to find some confirmation on this

Comment: You ask how reactivity works: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Let's first talk about updates to the DOM.**

In general, each data property in Vue instance has its own `watcher`.

You can narrow it down to 3 layers:

1. Vue Instance
2. Virtual DOM
3. DOM

---

Vue instance watches the Virtual DOM.

Virtual DOM is a representation of the real DOM but parsed in `JS` (much faster than the "real" DOM).

Then when we modify some property, Vue instance re-creates the "New" Virtual DOM (The "Template") and checks for differences between the "Old" Virtual DOM. If it is different then it only updates that particular part in "real" DOM.

---

**`beforeUpdate()` and `updated()` hooks.**

Once `mounted()` there is an ongoing lifecycle, that is whenever the data changes that require the DOM to update, both hooks are triggered - `beforeUpdate()` and `update()`.

**Note:** `beforeUpdate()` and `update()` are not executed if the DOM was has not been changed - even if you trigger an event.

Have a look below at the example you can see that `beforeUpdate()` and `update()` hooks are executed only the first time after pressing the button. Every next time, the `click` is triggered but the DOM is not changed, thus the hooks are not triggered.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Vue instance'
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log('beforeUpdate')
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('update')
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <button @click="title='changed'">Update</button>
</div>
```

---

**Conclusion:**

Based on the above, we can see that `beforeUpdate()` and `updated()` hooks are called when the "real" DOM is updated **>** which is caused by changes in Virtual DOM **>** which is caused by changes in Vue instance that reflects the changes to the Virtual DOM.

So in other words the component will re-render when any reactive dependency of the template changes.

This includes: `props`, `data`, and `computed` properties.

Comment: What do you precisely mean by "which is caused by changes in Vue instance."? What is a "change in Vue instance"?

Comment: In this case, it basically means the change that affects the "old" Virtual DOM, which will then trigger an update on the "real" DOM. So it could be caused by `props`, `data`, `computed` property.

Comment: I wrote in my question that I actually see the 'beforeUpdate' and 'updated' hooks triggered without props and data having changed. So there must be something else included in "change in Vue instance"!

Comment: "This includes: props, data, and computed properties." Is this an exhaustive list? Can I find this anywhere in the official documentation?

Comment: What you need to focus on here is what exactly changes the Virtual DOM - only then `beforeUpdate()` and `updated()` hooks are executed. Wherever the change comes from, whether it is a `computed` property, `data`, `props` even a `method` if its execution reflects triggers to the changes in Virtual DOM. If you want to know exactly what is happening in your specific scenario then feel free to provide a demo for us to be able to determine exactly what is happening (more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983349/what-is-the-difference-between-updated-hook-and-watchers-in-vuejs).

Comment: Easy explanation!! You could then argue, to increase performance we should divide the app to smallest component ever possible. Because if any reactive dependency changes it will only re-render that part of the app (small component) instead of the bloated component.